# Magento sub-domain redirecting to main domain even in separate server and DB

Tags: magento, amazon-web-services, nginx

I have live magento site yyy.com configured using nginx in linux AWS AMI its using AWS RDS for database. 
For the development purpose i have created the development server from the current live server image and for the development purpose 
i have created a sub-domain dev.yyy.com and for the development also i created a new RDS server and the dumped the live server databases content. 
I have changed both the secure to insecure URL from yyy.com to dev.yyy.com in the core-config-data and upadted the dev database details in the local.xml 
config file also and clear the cache and session folder.

The issue is if I load the dev.yyy.com means its taking me to yyy.com.

I put new index.php containing "Hi this test"vinstead of magento index.php in the dev.yyy.com root directory means i can see Hi this test in the browser when i load dev.yyy.com.

Is there any configuration in nginx like return or redirect to resolve this issue.

and if anyone tell me this nginx related problem or magento files related problem. It will be very helpful for me to check further.

I working on this 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

I would check all the values in `core_config_data` to see if `yyy.com` is still in there.  You may have missed a config or there could be a customization redirecting you.

Also check your `.htaccess` for any redirect rules that shouldn't be there.

Also make sure you've cleared the contents of `var/cache/` and `var/full_page_cache/`.

Comment: Oh, missed that.  No it will not.  You will need to look in your nginx configs (usually in `/etc/nginx/`)

Comment: do you how to use return or rewrite in nginx to resolve my above problem. i have tried every available options that shown when i googled about this problem no results